# Distributing both python 2 and 3 bytecode files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Python code that works in both Python 2.7 and 3.x.  However some of my modules need to be distributed as compiled, .pyc files rather than .py source files.

Is there a way to distribute .pyc files for both Python versions in the same package, i.e. both 2.7 and 3.x .pyc files in the same folder, and have the Python interpreter determine which one to use?

Comment: I'm sure if I don't ask, someone else will ... Why do you need to distribute some of the files as .pyc files instead of distributing regular .py files?

Comment: .pyc files have a magic number which includes the python version, but distributing .pyc files is not recommended, they are not guaranteed to be portable on different machine architectures or implementations.

Comment: because we have implementation details that we do not wish to make visible for some parts of our code.

Comment: You can uncompyle a pyc very easily https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncompyle2 so your effort even if it worked would be in vain

Comment: Making a pyc file is not secure!!!

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but in our case there is a difference between "I gave you the source"  vs "We decomplied this" in terms of providing support.

Comment: @NateWhite, I still think you are really going down a wrong path, if the people using the code could understand the source they can almost certainly get the source from the pyc, is obfuscation of the code your main goal?

Comment: I am fully aware of the arguments for providing the the source.  And regardless of weather or not I actually agree with them, I am not in a position to set policy on what is provided as a .pyc vs a .py file.

Comment: The format is meant for short-lived serialized objects, so its representation can change with each Python version.  The python major versions, e.g. 3.4 v. 3.5, must be the same on all machines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run code using both 3.2 and 2.7 Python interpreter in same project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985688/how-to-run-code-using-both-3-2-and-2-7-python-interpreter-in-same-project)